# Error in calling Stored Procedure(MySql) through Java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

Am creating a java code to call a stored procedure from mysql Db.
But am getting this following error when i compile the code. I have attached the code. Am a beginner to stored procedures looking for some help.Thanks in advance. 
        Stored Procedure:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_in_out_status_for_manager`(IN id int, OUT date_info date,out empname varchar(35),
        out EmpID varchar(10),
        out CardId Varchar(10),
        out EntryTime Datetime,
        out ExitTime datetime,
        out WorkTime time)
        BEGIN
        SELECT Date,empname,EmpID,CardID,EntryTime,ExitTime,WorkTime from pax_attd
        join employee_master on right(pax_attd.EmpID,3)=employee_master.employee_id
        where ((employee_master.reporting_employee_id=id) and (date=date_info));

        END

        Java Code:

        package mysqltoxl;
        import java.sql.*;

        public class JDBCExample {
           // JDBC driver name and database URL
           static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
           static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/PaxWeb";

           //  Database credentials
           static final String USER = "root";
           static final String PASS = "pax";

           public static void main(String[] args) {
               Connection conn = null;
               CallableStatement stmt = null;
               try{
                  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                  //STEP 3: Open a connection
                  System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

                  //STEP 4: Execute a query
                  System.out.println("Creating statement...");
                  String sql = "{call get_in_out_status_for_manager(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";
                  stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);

                  //Bind IN parameter first, then bind OUT parameter
                  int EmpId = 401;

                  stmt.setInt(1,EmpId);



                  // Because second parameter is OUT so register it

                    stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.DATE);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.TIME);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.TIME);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.TIME);

                  //Use execute method to run stored procedure.
                  System.out.println("Executing stored procedure..." );
                  stmt.execute();


                    Date Date = stmt.getDate(2);
                    String empname = stmt.getString(3);
                    String EmpID = stmt.getString(4);
                    String CardId = stmt.getString(4);
                    Date EntryTime= stmt.getDate(5);
                    Date ExitTime = stmt.getDate(6);
                    Time WorkTime = stmt.getTime(7); 
                  System.out.println("Emp Name with ID:" + 
                           EmpId + " is " + empname);
                  stmt.close();
                  conn.close();
               }catch(SQLException se){
                  //Handle errors for JDBC
                  se.printStackTrace();
               }catch(Exception e){
                  //Handle errors for Class.forName
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }finally{
                  //finally block used to close resources
                  try{
                     if(stmt!=null)
                        stmt.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se2){
                  }// nothing we can do
                  try{
                     if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se){
                     se.printStackTrace();
                  }//end finally try
               }//end try
               System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            }//end main
            }//end JDBCExample
```

My Error is :

```
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
Executing stored procedure...
Emp Name with ID:401 is null
Goodbye!
```

Answer (score 0):

change the out parameter names and add into clause in select statement.
create procedure as follows:

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_in_out_status_for_manager`( 
    IN id int, 
    OUT date_info date,
    out **out_empname** varchar(35),
        out **out_EmpID** varchar(10),
        out **out_CardId** Varchar(10),
        out **out_EntryTime** Datetime,
        out **out_ExitTime** datetime,
        out **out_WorkTime** time)
        BEGIN
        SELECT Date,empname,EmpID,CardID,EntryTime,ExitTime,WorkTime 
    **into date_info,out_empname,out_EmpID,out_CardID,out_EntryTime,out_ExitTime,out_WorkTime**
    from pax_attd
        join employee_master on right(pax_attd.EmpID,3)=employee_master.employee_id
        where ((employee_master.reporting_employee_id=id) and (date=date_info));

```
    END
```

Comment: out parameter will not bring any value into procedure but it will return some value to the java program. here date_info is an out parameter and used in condition clause. that is the problem please check once.

Comment: yeah i checked and changed as "IN date_info date" , even then the result is same .

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to put into in the stored procedure?

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_in_out_status_for_manager`(IN id int, **IN** date_info date,out empname varchar(35),
        out EmpID varchar(10),
        out CardId Varchar(10),
        out EntryTime Datetime,
        out ExitTime datetime,
        out WorkTime time)
        BEGIN
        SELECT Date,empname,EmpID,CardID,EntryTime,ExitTime,WorkTime **INTO** DATE_INFO, EMPNAME, EMPID, CARDID, ENTRYTIME, EXITTIME, WORKTIME from pax_attd
        join employee_master on right(pax_attd.EmpID,3)=employee_master.employee_id
        where ((employee_master.reporting_employee_id=id) and (date=date_info));

```
    END
```

Comment: date_info supposed to be IN and you need to set it in your Java Code. Because from your select query you use date_info parameter in where clause.

Comment: you already put it as IN but have you declare on the Java Code?
int EmpId = 401;
stmt.setInt(1,EmpId);
stmt.java.sql.Date.valueOf(2,"2013-09-04");